# textbox validation in vb6 (disable paste option) 

Tags: vb6

validation on textbox in vb 6.0
 i tried

```
Private Sub Text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)    
    If Not (KeyAscii = vbKeyBack Or KeyAscii = vbKeyDelete Or KeyAscii = vbKeySpace Or (KeyAscii >= Asc("1")     And KeyAscii <= Asc("9"))) Then
    KeyAscii = 0
End If
```

but now i want that paste option should disable when i right click on textbox

Comment: This is really a bad idea. Why make it hard for the user? Don’t interfere with legitimate user actions – validate *afterwards*!

Comment: I would agree with Konrad. However, in hinesight, given your own answer it looks like all you realy wanted to know is how you can manage only numbers to get entered into a textbox and not how to disable the paste item on the context menu. In that case you are right to see if you can ensure only numbers can be entered. None the less the question could have been better in asking what it is you actually needed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this is quite similar:

```
Private Sub Text1_Change()

Dim i As Long, sTemp As String

    For i = 1 To Len(Text1)
        If InStr(1, "0123456789", Mid$(Text1, i, 1)) > 0 Then sTemp = sTemp & Mid$(Text1, i, 1)
    Next

    Text1 = sTemp
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prevent right-click menu items from being used on the textbox you can create your own context menu.

Then, using API calls you need to unhook the default menu from the textbox and hook up the custom menu.
(I'm not aware of other APIs which only let you disable/hide items in the existing context menu)

The downside off course is that any menu item you want to keep such as copy or delete you need to write the code for yourself.

You can find a very good explenation on how to do this here [**Disable right click menu inside a textbox**](http://63.236.73.220/showthread.php?p=1242699) and here [**Weird reaction on a popup menu**](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?s=&threadid=209682&highlight=End)

*What next,..* what is if the user uses CTRL+V to paste? Or what if the user has paste mapped to different key combinations, other than CTRL+V?

***Validate the data instead?***

You can end up writing a lot of code trying to prevent data entry. Why not save that work and instead let the user enter what they like and use the validate event to validate the data?

I wrote a sample on another site on using the validate event of a textbox here: [**Validate Value Is Numeric**](http://63.236.73.220/showthread.php?p=3707433#post3707433). That link also has a vb6 demo project I put together attached in the post.

The type of validation is irrelevant I suppose, it simply demonstrates using the validate event allows you to focus on validating the data, rather than trying to code every single possible way you can think of trying to prevent data to be entered in the first place.

*The Validate event is triggered before lostfocus and before the next control's getfocus.
Only if the validate event is **not** told to **cancel** the action, will the lostfocus event and any subsequent event be executed.
The Validate event is intended to be used to ensure the control's value is validated before executing any other event.*

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Text1_Change()
    If Text1.Tag <> Text1.Text Then
        Text1.Text = Text1.Tag
        Text1.SelStart = Len(Text1.Text)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    Text1.Tag = Text1.Text & Chr(KeyAscii)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Old problem but still relevant with legacy projects.

The solution proposed by Sam Sylvester is interesting but doesn't allow you to delete characters (use backspace) and appends the 22 ASCII character (Ctrl + V) in the textbox (which is bad).

This solution I found worked for me (prevents paste using Ctrl + V and also using the context menu):

```
Dim preventPasteFlag As Boolean

Private Sub Text1_Change()
    If preventPasteFlag Then
        Text1.Text = Text1.Tag
        preventPasteFlag = False
    Else
        Text1.Tag = Text1.Text
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If KeyAscii = 22 Then
       preventPasteFlag = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Text1_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    If Button = 2 Then
       preventPasteFlag = True
    End If
End Sub
```